# How to reflect the changes made in edit mode of datagridview in the textbox

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datagridview which is editable. I have a textbox below it. I am entering the values in the grid view on run time and calculating the total in the textbox below it. The problem is, whenever i change the value in the grid view, the textbox retains the previous value and adds the new value to previous. I dont want the old value to be added. I wrote this code

```
private void grdPurchase_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
        //this.grdPurchase.Refresh();
       (grdPurchase.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() != "")
        string value = grdPurchase.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {

            float val = float.Parse(value);
            total = val;
            if (vapasi1 == "Yes")
            {
                if((e.r
                vtot += total;
                txt_forvapasitotal.Text = vtot.ToString();
                float vapsitot = float.Parse(txt_forvapasitotal.Text);
                float vapsicalculate = (vapsitot * a);
                float tax = vapsicalculate / 100;
                float with_vapasi = vtot + tax;
                txt_withvapasi.Text = Convert.ToString(with_vapasi);

            }
            else
            {
                nvtot += total;
                txt_withoutvapasitot.Text = nvtot.ToString();
            }
            txt_vapasiincludedtot.Text = (float.Parse(txt_withvapasi.Text) + float.Parse(txt_withoutvapasitot.Text)).ToString();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the event DataGridView.CellValueChanged. An example can be find on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged

Answer (score 0):

amend this line `vtot += total` to `vtot = total`

```
                   if (vapasi1 == "Yes")
                    {
                        if((e.r
                        vtot = total;
                        txt_forvapasitotal.Text = vtot.ToString();
                        float vapsitot = float.Parse(txt_forvapasitotal.Text);
                        float vapsicalculate = (vapsitot * a);
                        float tax = vapsicalculate / 100;
                        float with_vapasi = vtot + tax;
                        txt_withvapasi.Text = Convert.ToString(with_vapasi);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nvtot = total;
                        txt_withoutvapasitot.Text = nvtot.ToString();
                    }
```

Comment: Let me tell you it's really hard to understand your style. Anyways, I presume there could be cached values from any of earlier execution cycle.

Comment: I have multiple rows in datagridview and i want to add the value of all the rows in the column. But incase user changes any of the values in the grid the textbox should reflect the new value not the old. If i do not add as u suggested, it will overwrite the values of textbox and will finally give me the last value of the column and not the sum.

Comment: In that case can you amend your logic in such a way that the tax calculation can be made just before you show it on textbox. Do your tax calculation in this line."txt_vapasiincludedtot.Text = (float.Parse(txt_withvapasi.Text) + float.Parse(txt_withoutvapasitot.Text)).ToString();"

Comment: thanks s_nair, i used cellvaluechange event. its working.. :)